# NIntegrate and Part issues

Tags: numerical-integration, list-manipulation

I'm trying to numerically evaluate an integral. To try and speed up the process, I decided to calculate some values that will be needed in advance using Parallel Tables. This is what I have:

```
TabelaZeros = ParallelTable[N[BesselJZero[m, n]], {m, 0, 4}, {n, 1, 5}];
TabelaBessel = ParallelTable[N[BesselJ[m, r*TabelaZeros[[m + 1, n]]]], {m, 0, 4}, 
    {n, 1, 5}, {r,0, 2, 0.1}];
```

I believe these are correct.

I then try to evaluate my integral:

```
ParallelTable[NIntegrate[f[r, θ]*Cos[m*θ]*TabelaBessel[[m + 1, n, r*10 + 1]]*r, 
    {r, 0, 2, 0.1}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}], {m, 0, 4}, {n, 1, 5}]
```

And I get several errors:

```
Part::pkspec1 : The expression cannot be used as a part specification
NIntegrate::inumr : The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values
```

Comment: `f[r, θ]` is undefined, and `{r,0, 2, 0.1}` has a different meaning in `Table` and `NIntegrate`.

Comment: I see. I looked through the documentation but didn't find a way to define a step for r similar to how I've done it in the table. Is this possible?

Comment: `Nintegrate` requires an at least piecewise continuous integrand, whereas your table provides only discrete values.  Try `FunctionInterpolation`.

Comment: Or if you're trying to integrate a list of values, see the advice at the top of [`ListIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FunctionApproximations/ref/ListIntegrate.html)